# How do I batch convert .xlsx to PDF from folder using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I have a pretty mundane task quarterly where I need to convert 40 files to PDF from XLSX. I have some code that can print one file as a pdf but not multiple pages and it cannot print multiple files. I want to access the folder, open the .xlsx and the print them to a pdf.

To take it a step further and my code does not, I want to only print two sheets named: "Page 1" and "Page 2"

I have tried one file and that works with a slightly modified code.

```
import os
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

source = r"C:\Users\user1\.spyder-py3\QAR"
output = r"C:\Users\user1\.spyder-py3\QAR"

dir_list = os.listdir(source)
os.chdir(source)

for i in range(len(dir_list)):
    filename = dir_list[i]
    print(filename)
    books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)

    
    for file in range(len(filename)):
          ws = books.Worksheets[1]
          ws.Visible = 1
          ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, filename + '\.pdf')
```

I would ideally like to see the files saved as individual pdfs with two sheets, Page 1 and Page 2.

I can get the Excel files open or save one excel as a pdf with one page but can't seem to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

I can write the pseudo code on how to achieve this. Once I am in front of a laptop, I will provide code blocks.

Part 1 - Loop through one or many folders and pick each file. Pass file to part 2 of your logic.
In this part, move your processed files to a Processed folder which will be created by the Part 1 (first time).

```
This code will loop thru open the workbooks in silent mode.

Dim oXL As Application
Set oXL = New Application
oXL.Visible = False

Dim oXLWB As Workbook

For i = 1 To 1
    Set oXLWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsx")
    Debug.Print oXLWB.Worksheets(1).Name
    oXLWB.Close
Next

oXL.Quit
```

Part 2 - Through VBA open each file in a silent mode. Print selective sheets based on sheet name. Print this list of selective sheets with the PDF format (which I believe you know).
In this part, in case case of any error, add the error to the filename. Obviously dont move this file to Processed folder and move on.

Let me know if this makes sense and if you make any progress.
Good luck

Comment: That would be incredibly helpful, from what I can gather right now my first loop is getting the name of each file in the folder but excel cannot open them with the Open.Workbook function. I am working on that right now but really appreciate it.

Comment: Update, I can now open each of the pdfs although not silently, not sure how to do that yet. Would I use xl.visible = false for that?

Comment: Pranav, sorry for the delay! Wow work has been busy. I am still having an issue combining the python and vba. This code looks like strictly VBA. Still continuing to play with it

Comment: Still looking to figure this out, I am unable to save the files. My code is below and it says that their is some error.  

for i in range(len(dir_list)): 
    filename = dir_list[i] 
    print(filename) 
    file = xl.Workbooks.Open((source + "/"+ filename))
    ws = file.Worksheets[0]
    ws.Visible = False
    ws.SaveAs(output + "/" + filename, FileFormat = 56)
    #ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(1, output + "/" + filename + '.pdf',0,1)
    ws.close()

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Try a direct folder path the way I mentioned. See if that works. Then slowly fix the concatenated.